# SpreadSheet with Comments is not working with Open XML

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheet, openxml, openxml-sdk

We are trying to export excel with comments using Open Xml. I have tried with below code snippet and its showing comments in the Sheet Object but when exported to excel the comments are not displaying in the cells after opening excel.

```
public byte[] ExportJsonDatatoExcelWithComments()
{

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheet.AddWorkbookPart();

    workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
    Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());
    //OpenSheet
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

    var sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "test" };
    sheets.Append(sheet);
    
    WorksheetCommentsPart worksheetCommentsPart1 = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetCommentsPart>();
    GenerateWorksheetCommentsPart1Content(worksheetCommentsPart1);

    OpenXmlWriter DataWriter = OpenXmlWriter.Create(worksheetPart);
    DataWriter.WriteStartElement(sheetData);
    DataWriter.WriteStartElement(worksheetPart.Worksheet);
    
    //closedata
    DataWriter.WriteEndElement();
    DataWriter.Close();
    //
    //render
    // worksheetPart = null;
    workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
    spreadsheet.Save();
    spreadsheet.Close();
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}

public void GenerateWorksheetCommentsPart1Content(WorksheetCommentsPart worksheetCommentsPart)
{
    Comments comments1 = new Comments() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "xr" } };


    Authors authors1 = new Authors();
    Author author1 = new Author();
    author1.Text = "User1";

    authors1.Append(author1);

    CommentList commentList1 = new CommentList();

    Comment comment1 = new Comment() { Reference = "A3", AuthorId = (UInt32Value)12, ShapeId = (UInt32Value)10, Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
    comment1.SetAttribute(new OpenXmlAttribute("xr", "uid", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision", "{811649EF-4CB5-4311-BE14-228133003BE4}"));

    CommentText commentText1 = new CommentText();

    Run run1 = new Run();

    RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
    FontSize fontSize3 = new FontSize() { Val = 9D };
    Color color3 = new Color() { Indexed = (UInt32Value)81U };
    RunFont runFont1 = new RunFont() { Val = "Tahoma" };
    RunPropertyCharSet runPropertyCharSet1 = new RunPropertyCharSet() { Val = 1 };

    runProperties1.Append(fontSize3);
    runProperties1.Append(color3);
    runProperties1.Append(runFont1);
    runProperties1.Append(runPropertyCharSet1);
    Text text1 = new Text() { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };
    text1.Text = "This is my comment!\nThis is line 2!\n";

    run1.Append(runProperties1);
    run1.Append(text1);

    commentText1.Append(run1);

    comment1.Append(commentText1);

    commentList1.Append(comment1);

    comments1.Append(authors1);
    comments1.Append(commentList1);
   
    worksheetCommentsPart.Comments = comments1;
}
```

Please let me know what is the issue with the code and how can we show comments for particular cell.

Comment: Is viewing of comments active in Excel when you open the file? You can toggle this setting by pressing Shift + F2

Comment: Yes Comments is active and when i click on comments for the sheet, it shows me no Comments

Comment: After a bit of research, it does not look that straightforward. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/592598/3110695) which makes you rethink if you want to add comments. If you still need to, then maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3494858/3110695) will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public byte[] ExportJsonDatatoExcelWithComments()
{

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheet.AddWorkbookPart();

    workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
    Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());
    //OpenSheet
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

    var sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "test" };
    sheets.Append(sheet);
    
    WorksheetCommentsPart worksheetCommentsPart1 = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetCommentsPart>();
    GenerateWorksheetCommentsPart1Content(worksheetCommentsPart1);

    OpenXmlWriter DataWriter = OpenXmlWriter.Create(worksheetPart);
    DataWriter.WriteStartElement(sheetData);
    DataWriter.WriteStartElement(worksheetPart.Worksheet);
    
    //closedata
    DataWriter.WriteEndElement();
    DataWriter.Close();
    //
    //render
    // worksheetPart = null;
    workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
    spreadsheet.Save();
    spreadsheet.Close();
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}

 /// <summary>
        /// Adds all the comments defined in the commentsToAddDict dictionary to the worksheet
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="worksheetPart">Worksheet Part</param>
        /// <param name="commentsToAddDict">Dictionary of cell references as the key (ie. A1) and the comment text as the value</param>
        public static void InsertComments(WorksheetPart worksheetPart, Dictionary<string, string> commentsToAddDict)
        {
            if (commentsToAddDict.Any())
            {
                string commentsVmlXml = string.Empty;

                // Create all the comment VML Shape XML
                foreach (var commentToAdd in commentsToAddDict)
                {
                    commentsVmlXml += GetCommentVMLShapeXML(commentToAdd.Key.Substring(0,1), commentToAdd.Key.Substring(1));
                }

                // The VMLDrawingPart should contain all the definitions for how to draw every comment shape for the worksheet
                VmlDrawingPart vmlDrawingPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<VmlDrawingPart>();
                using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(vmlDrawingPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create), Encoding.UTF8))
                {

                    writer.WriteRaw("<xml xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\"\r\n xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\"\r\n xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">\r\n <o:shapelayout v:ext=\"edit\">\r\n  <o:idmap v:ext=\"edit\" data=\"1\"/>\r\n" +
                    "</o:shapelayout><v:shapetype id=\"_x0000_t202\" coordsize=\"21600,21600\" o:spt=\"202\"\r\n  path=\"m,l,21600r21600,l21600,xe\">\r\n  <v:stroke joinstyle=\"miter\"/>\r\n  <v:path gradientshapeok=\"t\" o:connecttype=\"rect\"/>\r\n </v:shapetype>"
                    + commentsVmlXml + "</xml>");
                }

                // Create the comment elements
                foreach (var commentToAdd in commentsToAddDict)
                {
                    WorksheetCommentsPart worksheetCommentsPart = worksheetPart.WorksheetCommentsPart ?? worksheetPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetCommentsPart>();

                    // We only want one legacy drawing element per worksheet for comments
                    if (worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<LegacyDrawing>().SingleOrDefault() == null)
                    {
                        string vmlPartId = worksheetPart.GetIdOfPart(vmlDrawingPart);
                        LegacyDrawing legacyDrawing = new LegacyDrawing() { Id = vmlPartId };
                        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(legacyDrawing);
                    }

                    Comments comments;
                    bool appendComments = false;
                    if (worksheetPart.WorksheetCommentsPart.Comments != null)
                    {
                        comments = worksheetPart.WorksheetCommentsPart.Comments;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        comments = new Comments();
                        appendComments = true;
                    }

                    // We only want one Author element per Comments element
                    if (worksheetPart.WorksheetCommentsPart.Comments == null)
                    {
                        Authors authors = new Authors();
                        Author author = new Author();
                        author.Text = "Author Name";
                        authors.Append(author);
                        comments.Append(authors);
                    }

                    CommentList commentList;
                    bool appendCommentList = false;
                    if (worksheetPart.WorksheetCommentsPart.Comments != null &&
                        worksheetPart.WorksheetCommentsPart.Comments.Descendants<CommentList>().SingleOrDefault() != null)
                    {
                        commentList = worksheetPart.WorksheetCommentsPart.Comments.Descendants<CommentList>().Single();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        commentList = new CommentList();
                        appendCommentList = true;
                    }

                    Comment comment = new Comment() { Reference = commentToAdd.Key, AuthorId = (UInt32Value)0U };

                    CommentText commentTextElement = new CommentText();

                    Run run = new Run();

                    RunProperties runProperties = new RunProperties();
                    Bold bold = new Bold();
                    FontSize fontSize = new FontSize() { Val = 8D };
                    Color color = new Color() { Indexed = (UInt32Value)81U };
                    RunFont runFont = new RunFont() { Val = "Tahoma" };
                    RunPropertyCharSet runPropertyCharSet = new RunPropertyCharSet() { Val = 1 };

                    runProperties.Append(bold);
                    runProperties.Append(fontSize);
                    runProperties.Append(color);
                    runProperties.Append(runFont);
                    runProperties.Append(runPropertyCharSet);
                    Text text = new Text();
                    text.Text = commentToAdd.Value;

                    run.Append(runProperties);
                    run.Append(text);

                    commentTextElement.Append(run);
                    comment.Append(commentTextElement);
                    commentList.Append(comment);

                    // Only append the Comment List if this is the first time adding a comment
                    if (appendCommentList)
                    {
                        comments.Append(commentList);
                    }

                    // Only append the Comments if this is the first time adding Comments
                    if (appendComments)
                    {
                        worksheetCommentsPart.Comments = comments;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the VML Shape XML for a comment. It determines the positioning of the
        /// comment in the excel document based on the column name and row index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="columnName">Column name containing the comment</param>
        /// <param name="rowIndex">Row index containing the comment</param>
        /// <returns>VML Shape XML for a comment</returns>
        private static string GetCommentVMLShapeXML(string columnName, string rowIndex)
        {
            string commentVmlXml = string.Empty;

            // Parse the row index into an int so we can subtract one
            int commentRowIndex;
            if (int.TryParse(rowIndex, out commentRowIndex))
            {
                commentRowIndex -= 1;

                commentVmlXml = "<v:shape id=\"" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + "\" type=\"#_x0000_t202\" style=\'position:absolute;\r\n  margin-left:59.25pt;margin-top:1.5pt;width:96pt;height:55.5pt;z-index:1;\r\n  visibility:hidden\' fillcolor=\"#ffffe1\" o:insetmode=\"auto\">\r\n  <v:fill color2=\"#ffffe1\"/>\r\n" +
                "<v:shadow on=\"t\" color=\"black\" obscured=\"t\"/>\r\n  <v:path o:connecttype=\"none\"/>\r\n  <v:textbox style=\'mso-fit-shape-to-text:true'>\r\n   <div style=\'text-align:left\'></div>\r\n  </v:textbox>\r\n  <x:ClientData ObjectType=\"Note\">\r\n   <x:MoveWithCells/>\r\n" +
                "<x:SizeWithCells/>\r\n   <x:Anchor>\r\n" + GetAnchorCoordinatesForVMLCommentShape(columnName, rowIndex) + "</x:Anchor>\r\n   <x:AutoFill>False</x:AutoFill>\r\n   <x:Row>" + commentRowIndex + "</x:Row>\r\n   <x:Column>" + GetColumnIndexFromName(columnName) + "</x:Column>\r\n  </x:ClientData>\r\n </v:shape>";
            }

            return commentVmlXml;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the coordinates for where on the excel spreadsheet to display the VML comment shape
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="columnName">Column name of where the comment is located (ie. B)</param>
        /// <param name="rowIndex">Row index of where the comment is located (ie. 2)</param>
        /// <returns><see cref="<x:Anchor>"/> coordinates in the form of a comma separated list</returns>
        private static string GetAnchorCoordinatesForVMLCommentShape(string columnName, string rowIndex)
        {
            string coordinates = string.Empty;
            int startingRow = 0;
            int startingColumn = GetColumnIndexFromName(columnName).Value;

            // From (upper right coordinate of a rectangle)
            // [0] Left column
            // [1] Left column offset
            // [2] Left row
            // [3] Left row offset
            // To (bottom right coordinate of a rectangle)
            // [4] Right column
            // [5] Right column offset
            // [6] Right row
            // [7] Right row offset
            List<int> coordList = new List<int>(8) { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

            if (int.TryParse(rowIndex, out startingRow))
            {
                // Make the row be a zero based index
                startingRow -= 1;

                coordList[0] = startingColumn + 1; // If starting column is A, display shape in column B
                coordList[1] = 15;
                coordList[2] = startingRow;
                coordList[4] = startingColumn + 3; // If starting column is A, display shape till column D
                coordList[5] = 15;
                coordList[6] = startingRow + 3; // If starting row is 0, display 3 rows down to row 3

                // The row offsets change if the shape is defined in the first row
                if (startingRow == 0)
                {
                    coordList[3] = 2;
                    coordList[7] = 16;
                }
                else
                {
                    coordList[3] = 10;
                    coordList[7] = 4;
                }

                coordinates = string.Join(",", coordList.ConvertAll<string>(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
            }

            return coordinates;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Given just the column name (no row index), it will return the zero based column index.
        /// Note: This method will only handle columns with a length of up to two (ie. A to Z and AA to ZZ). 
        /// A length of three can be implemented when needed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="columnName">Column Name (ie. A or AB)</param>
        /// <returns>Zero based index if the conversion was successful; otherwise null</returns>
        public static int? GetColumnIndexFromName(string columnName)
        {
            int? columnIndex = null;

            string[] colLetters = Regex.Split(columnName, "([A-Z]+)");
            colLetters = colLetters.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();

            if (colLetters.Count() <= 2)
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (string col in colLetters)
                {
                    List<char> Letters = new List<char>() { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J' };
                    List<char> col1 = colLetters.ElementAt(index).ToCharArray().ToList();
                    int? indexValue = Letters.IndexOf(col1.ElementAt(index));

                    if (indexValue != -1)
                    {
                        // The first letter of a two digit column needs some extra calculations
                        if (index == 0 && colLetters.Count() == 2)
                        {
                            columnIndex = columnIndex == null ? (indexValue + 1) * 26 : columnIndex + ((indexValue + 1) * 26);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            columnIndex = columnIndex == null ? indexValue : columnIndex + indexValue;
                        }
                    }

                    index++;
                }
            }

            return columnIndex;
        }
```